# CS-Script for SublimeText not working (C# Intellisense)

Tags: c#, macos, unity3d, mono

I'd like to use C# Intellisense for [SublimeText 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (OS X). I need it to develop games with Unity3D.

So I installed [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-sublime) and [CS-Script](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script-sublime) for it. OmniSharp works so far but CS-Script doesn't.

When I click the About-menu of CS-Script it outputs the first two lines only:

```
CS-Script.ST3 - C# intellisense and execution plugin (v1.2.8)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

According to the [developer's homepage](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script-sublime/wiki/Installing-plugin-on-OS-X) of CS-Script this happens when...

```
...mono cannot be located the "about output" (above) will be truncated and
consist of only two first lines.
Such a truncation is caused by the plugin's inability to execute mono cscs.exe,
which is responsible for printing the remaining part of the output content.
```

So I changed the path of [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) (yes, I already installed Mono) in the file cs-script.sublime-settings to

```
"mono_path": "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.0.0/bin/mono",
```

and the path of cscs.exe to

```
"cscs_path": "/Users/***/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/cs-script-sublime/bin/cscs.exe",
```

Still not working and I don't know what I might have done wrong.

Comment: How is this related to `Unity3d`?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I use it for Unity3D.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use the Visual Studio Community Edition for mac? It comes with Intellisense built in and is also supported by Unity3D which allows you to attach your script to the editor and debug in real time.

I don't see a reason to use Sublime Text here other than maybe disk space related issues.

Comment: Because I like SublimeText for its speed and slick interface design (and it doesn't use a lot of memory). Visual Studio is bloatware and a real memory hog.:(